# Blank space on right side and bottom on SubForm Control containing a Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I have a `mainForm` than contains a `subForm` control. The `subForm` control has a `report` as its `dataSourceObject`. I like to put `report` there as it hides the blank fields and gives a nice summary of items. However, when there are not enough items to populate the `report` then I see annoying spaces on the bottom and right side of the `subForm` control. 
Does anyone how can I avoid it?

Picture is attached:

[image: Blank Spaces on Right side and Bottom of Pic]

Comment: Looks like report width is just enough to fit the container with a scroll bar. Scroll bar doesn't show when records fully display so that space is allowance for scroll bar. Vertically, the report grows and shrinks. When it shrinks small enough there is left over blank space in the container. Why is this an issue on a form?

Comment: Actually, this container is a `subForm` in another `mainForm`. I have set a `backColor` theme for `mainForm` which is non-white. When this blank appears, it looks odd on the `mainForm`.

Comment: Think you are stuck with that when placing report on form.

Comment: Alright, then I think I better change the `detail' of `mainForm` `backColor` to white as well.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the form goes from records requiring a scroll bar to zero records on the form. Add some code to whatever refreshed the form to turn the scroll bars off then back on and it will fix the problem.

Me.Scrollbars = 0 ' to not show them.

Me.Scrollbars = 1 ' for horizontal only

Me.Scrollbars = 2 ' for vertical only

Me.Scrollbars = 3 ' for both horizontal and vertical